# How does Java Spring Async manage threads?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, threadpool

I want to write a Spring Boot application with non-blocking requests in mind.  In general, my controller methods are single-line methods, which just call a service method and then return, like this:

```
@RestController
class myController {
    ...
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getString(){
        return service.getString().get();
    }
}
```

Let's say I have a Service implementation which looks something like this:

```
@Service
class myService{
    ...
    @Async
    public CompleteableFuture<String> getString(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

(Assume I have elsewhere included `@EnableAsync`, and assume the controller code is modified to handle CompleteableFutures by extracting the String value and returning it)

When my controller calls my service, does Java still reserve a worker thread to wait on the return value from the Service, or is the worker thread returned to the thread pool until the service completes its work?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add more details to your post? What is the use case? Does it actually work this way? Cause it looks weird. If you want to process something async, why you are waiting for response from async method then? You should call async method and return something like 200 202 right way without waiting for async method completion.

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async

Comment: If you want a truly async architecture, you should use libraries like RxJava and Project Reactor.

Comment: @SergeiSirik The code looks weird because it's just a sample.  Replace the provided code with something that makes sense.  But the structure is the same.

Comment: @Andreas That documentation does not answer the question.  The question is, what happens to the thread that the controller is using when CompleteableFuture.get() is called?

Comment: @Ertai87 How about you show the controller code with the `get()` call you just mentioned? The code in the question wouldn't compile, because `getString()` returns a `CompleteableFuture<String>`, but the caller expects a `String`. Show the code you're actually asking about.

Comment: @Andreas Updated.

Comment: @Ertai87 Javadoc of [`CompletableFuture.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) says: *"**Waits** if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result"*. Which part of "wait" didn't you understand? The thread is put to sleep until the result it ready. The thread is **not** returned to the thread pool. How could it be?

Comment: If you want the request-processing thread to be release to process other requests, you need to make the controller do the asynchronous handling, as described in the [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async).

Comment: @Andreas I don't know enough about concurrent programming and threading to know why it /couldn't/ be, and my understanding is that similar functionality in other languages works like that (specifically NodeJS, although I don't know enough about that language to know if I was being BSed when that was explained to me)

Comment: Other languages does it at the controller layer too, not the service layer.

Answer (score 3):

> When my controller calls my service, does Java still reserve a worker thread to wait on the return value from the Service

No, your controller does not wait, the method `@Async` method is called asynchronously.

> or is the worker thread returned to the thread pool until the service completes its work?

By default when `@Async` method is called Spring uses `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` which starts a new thread for each invocation, so no thread pool is used. You can however provide your own Task Executor or use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` - [details](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  I understand a new thread is started for the async method execution.  What I want to know is when the caller wants to get the value from the service (e.g. caller calls CompleteableFuture.get()), will that block a thread if the future is not complete?

Comment: Yes, the controller **does** wait, since the controller calls `get()`, which waits.

Comment: @Ertai87 Yes, when you call `get()` on a `Future` and the compution is not available yet the call will block.